# iOS:Send multiple images to FTP Server

Tags: ios, objective-c, ftp

im using SCRFTPRequest for send image files to a FTP Server and its working now. but how if i want to try to send multiple images?
This is the method that i used:

```
NSString *ftpUrl=@"ftp://localhost";
NSString *strPortNumber=@"21";

NSString* escapedUrl = [linkURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *directoryName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",escapedUrl];


NSString *strurlUpload=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@%@/",ftpUrl,strPortNumber,directoryName];

NSString *getfilePath=filepath;
ftpRequest = [[SCRFTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strurlUpload] toUploadFile:getfilePath];
```

is there any other method or i have to use another library?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

you use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) tutorial it helpfull you

Comment: Hi, i 've used ASIHTTPRequest for several times, but this time my server is an FTP server, i don't quiet know if ASIHTTPRequst can connect to an FTP Server?thanks